# Laravel - How to create multiple user roles and assign privilege to them?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have to create an application in which there are 5 types of accounts

- Super admin
- Inventory admin
- Shop owner
- Shop manager
- User

So How can I create these multiple accounts with Laravel, should I use different middleware group for each. also, i have to create privileges with all.

Currently, I am using it with different middleware and session for each and separate tables in DB for each, but I don't think so that's a good way to do it.

What is the way to create these multiple accounts with Laravel.

@Thanks

Comment: How about creating a groups table and assign users to different groups?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to providing authentication services, Laravel also provides a simple way to authorize user actions against a given resource. Laravel's approach to **authorization** is simple, and there are two primary ways of authorizing actions: **gates and policies**. Please refer the Laravel documentation for more details.

[Authorization in Laravel 5.5](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authorization)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a column to users table called user_type and 
insert the decimal value for each user for example

```
Super admin = 1; 
Inventory admin = 2; 
Shop owner  = 3; 
Shop manager = 4; 
User = 5;
```

and based on the user_type you can do all your operation.

Answer (score 0):

As @Fawzan has said, if you only working with Roles (or a Group) then just create a groups table and then link each user to the appropriate group. You then have a single `user` table with a `groupID` for each user.

Then you could create a blade directive to help you in your app to check if a user has a specific role. (Place this inside your AppServiceProvider)

```
Blade::directive('hasRole', function ($role) {
    return auth()->user()->role->name = $role;
});

// Or a little more performant if you call the directive many times.

$roles = Role::all()->pluck('id', 'name')->toArray();
Blade::directive('hasRole', function ($role) use ($roles) {
    return auth()->user()->roleID == $roles[$role];
});
```